# No XML or code generated after creating a new Android Project

Tags: android

No XML file (the default Main.xml) is generated after I create a new Android Project.

I am using eclipse 4.2, ADT 20.0.3. ADT and SDK have been successfully installed, I think.

When I create a new project, after choosing BlankActivity and leaving out all the details for the activity in their default state and click *Finish* as described here: [Creating an Android Project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html), but the project wizard does *not* disappear though a project without any XML or any code has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

- Go the res folder then go to `layout` folder, and within it check the `main.xml` as the default file, you will find the XML.
- Fine if that's a problem. Let me show you the way to create a default Android Project in Eclipse.

`File --> New --> Android Project --> Write Project Name --> Next --> Select the SDK` 
`--> Give your package name as (eg: com.demo) --> finish.`

Comment: I know the steps, but no xml file generated. Only several empty folders have been generated.